# imagemagic library installation error for python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
> pip install imagemagic
```

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imagemagic (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for imagemagic

How can I resolve this error for Python3

Comment: Is your question related to **ImageMagick**?

Answer (score 1):

There's an ImageMagick project which requires python 2.5 :
[PythonMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/PythonMagick)

Comment: i am using python 3 so please can you suggest me how can i use it?

Comment: can you suggest me form where i can get that imagicmagik library or .exe for it

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.7.7-6-Q16-windows-dll.exe

Comment: This dll or exe file doesn't help you. You need to install it by using pip or making the whole package which in any way you're going to need python 2.5

Comment: If I install Python 2.7 then it will support?

Comment: Install 2.5 and read the documentation before doing anything!